# Different behavior of the same two operations on pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I write this code and the output was like this `B C D E`

```
char a[5] = {'A' , 'B' , 'C' , 'D'};
char *b = a + 2;
int i = 0 ;
for(i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i ++)
{
    *b = (a[i] + 1);
    printf("%c",*b);
}
```

But when I add reference like this :

```
char a[5] = {'A' , 'B' , 'C' , 'D'};
    char *b = &a + 2;
    int i = 0 ;
    for(i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i ++)
    {
        *b = (a[i] + 1);
        printf("%c",*b);
    }
```

the output become just `B`.

Comment: `&a + 2` is adding 2 * size of the array.  Certainly a compiler with warnings fully enabled would complain.  Save time, enable compiler warnings.

Comment: That should have generated a compiler warning. If it didn't you need to crank up your warnings and *fix* (not mask) the problems noted. In this case it's a pointer-arithmetic thing. `&a` is `char (*)[5]`, not `char*`, so naturally the expression `a+2` will yield a different result than `&a+2`. Adding salt to the wound, the latter invokes *undefined behavior* as well.

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with how pointer arithmetic is done.  When you add a value to a pointer, it increments the pointer by that value times the size of the type it references.

In the expression `a + 2`, `a` has type `char *`, so adding 2 increases the address by `2 * sizeof(char) == 2` bytes.

Given `&a + 2`, `&a` has type `char (*)[5]`, i.e. a pointer to an array of 5 `char`.  Adding 2 to this increases the address by `2 * sizeof(char [5]) == 10` bytes.  This points to a memory location past the end of the array, so dereferencing it invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in this cases leads to the loop exiting early.

You also have an invalid assignment in the second case, as you're trying to assign a value of type `char (*)[5]` to a value of type `char *`.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler should report error on

```
char a[5] = {'A' , 'B' , 'C' , 'D'};
char *b = &a + 2; // <<< compile error
int i = 0 ;
for(i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i ++)
{
    *b = (a[i] + 1);
    printf("%c",*b);
}
```

and if you remove the line that generates compile error, the output should be no difference from your first piece of code.